# Using NVD3 on top of D3. Not understanding how to include the 'assets' properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I found a neat chart library for D3 that can help make pretty graphs however, I am having issues with the [documentation](https://github.com/novus/nvd3).

At first, I downloaded the [scatterChart.html](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterChart.html) and I downloaded the **build** folder because I thought that is where it was getting all the files. But it said **nv is not defined** because file cannot be located. So then I tried doing it like it was on their [documentation], but still no luck.

I tried running it on localhost:: as well as just straight up opening the HTML.

Comment: I'm flagging this for closure as "a simple typographical error" as you've solved it by including more of the URL you needed. In future, feel free to add your solution as an *answer* to your own question - that is perfectly accepted practice and is much preferable to editing it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Okay... so I needed to use

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>`

instead of

`<script src="nv.d3.min.js"></script>`

The question is.. why didn't they just tell me to use that link? I know I sound like an idiot for thinking "`nv.d3.min.js`" would have worked without a http.